Readability in a number sequence steps using dots or dashes talking about
I’m working on a multi-level stepper that will help the user complete a process for an enterprise app. The main problem of the app has been sorted. Everything in the design looks fine and aligns with the business rules. However, when I was working on the sub-stepper, a question arose about whether to use dots or dashes in the sequence.
I have been searching for a document explaining or summarizing the response to back up a decision. However, I have not been lucky. So I want to ask you what makes you think the following approach if you see this
1 Group One - - - 2 Group Two - - - 3 Group Three
Option a:
1.1 Subtask One —— 1.2 Subtask Two —— 1.3 Subtask Three
Option b:
1-1 Subtask One —— 1-2 Subtask Two —— 1-3 Subtask Three
Also, the UI is defined, so I don't have to use points or dashes on the Group Sections. Another insight is that my team does not count on a researcher due to the tight budget.

Would breadcrumbs work for your case?

Not really. The page itself is using breadcrumbs to show where the user is located in the intranet.

Where is this used ? Can you tell a bit more about the context please !

Are the long em-dashes supposed to be part of the display or did you chose them to present the options here? Can you provide a screenshot on how these numbers are presented to the user (e.g. horizontally, as indicated here, or vertically? With colored backgrounds or without? etc.)

I use the dashes to make an example without using a wf because my question was more a UX writing question.

'Option a' is the correct one grammatically. If it is going to be purely textual without any visual elements, using the correct grammatical construction makes sense.
